# Consume GraphQL service from a Golang app

Tags: go, graphql

I have a Go Application that needs to consume a GraphQL service, now the documentation of graphQL is more oriented to the GraphQL server and not as a client. How can I do that?

I checked [this example](https://github.com/graphql-go/graphql/blob/master/examples/hello-world/main.go) but some things are not clear to me:

- Should I have a Resolve function to each field that I am going to retrieve?
- Should I  have defined the variable 'fields' with the data structure that I am expecting?
- Where can I find a very simple example of a GraphQL client in Golang?

Answer (score 2):

You should check this project: https://github.com/machinebox/graphql .

If you don't want to use an external library inside in your project, you could look the code and see how can you implement a simple client.

Answer (score 1):

One of the module that I would recommend is [shurcool](https://github.com/shurcooL/graphql)

```
client = graphql.NewClient("http://<<graphqlEndpoint>>", nil)

err := client.Query(context.Background(), &query, nil)
if err != nil {
    // Handle error.
}
fmt.Println(query.Me.Name)
```